# Is there a tool to generate .svf file for XMEGA programming?

Tags: avr, jtag, xmega

There is a tool called [avrsvf](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=4403%5d) that can be used to convert .hex file to .svf for JTAG programming of AVR devices. The tool, however, does not support XMEGA devices. Is there a similar tool for XMEGAs?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=92797&start=0[AVR forum][1]

on this page there is a link at the bottom by someone but it might not be for the one specific device he made it for.

> So I didnt find any hex-svf converter for xmega A series. 
>   I wrote a little utility (win consol): 
>   http://www.vfx.hu/avr/xmegasvf-111029.zip 
>   Supported ATxmega128A1 only.
>
> To do: 
>   - eeprom read/verify 
>   - lock bits read/verify 
>   - TCK period handler 
>   - all chip erase
>
> vfx.

I am not vfx nor do i know if this actually works, but it seems like using a bootloader + FLIP should work if that program doesn't. Although I assumed you can't load a bootloader onto your xmega.
http://www.batsocks.co.uk/readme/XMegaExamples.htm
http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8429.pdf

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for answering! What do you mean by "seems like a bootloader+FLIP"?

Comment: unfinished thought, editing.